# Only first table in create table statement being created

Tags: android, sqlite

The table "credentials" does show up in the adb shell.  I've checked logcat and it doesn't seem to report a problem...

```
   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table credentials (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "username text not null, password text not null, "
                + "lastupdate text);"
      + "create table user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "firstname text not null, "
                + "lastname text not null);"
      + "create table phone (_phoneid integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "userid integer not null, phonetype text not null, "
                + "phonenumber text not null);"
      + "create table email (_emailid integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "userid integer not null, emailtype text not null, "
                + "emailaddress text not null);"
      + "create table address (_addressid integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "userid integer not null, addresstype text not null, "
                + "address text not null);"
      + "create table instantmessaging (_imid integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "userid integer not null, imtype text not null, "
                + "imaccount text not null);";
```

I've been pouring over this and I bet its some silly syntax typo!  Or, at least I hope it is something trivial ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I suppose that you are using :

```
yourDB.execSQL("your statement");
```

If so, the google documentation mentions this :

> Execute a single SQL statement that is
>   not a query. For example, CREATE
>   TABLE, DELETE, INSERT, etc. Multiple
>   statements separated by ;s are not
>   supported. it takes a write lock

So you have to fragment each create table statement and repeat the query for each table.

Comment: And semi-colons are not allowed

Answer (score 8):

If I recall correctly, I encountered a similar problem and discovered that only 1 statement is executed per call to `execSQL()` or similar methods. Any extra statements are silently ignored.

Try separating each statement into separate strings and executing them separately, rather than a single string and single call.

For example:

```
private static final String TABLE_1 =
    "create table credentials (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "username text not null, password text not null, "
    + "lastupdate text);";

private static final String TABLE_2 =
    "create table user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "firstname text not null, "
    + "lastname text not null);";

private static final String TABLE_3 =
    "create table phone (_phoneid integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "userid integer not null, phonetype text not null, "
    + "phonenumber text not null);";

private static final String TABLE_4 =
    "create table email (_emailid integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "userid integer not null, emailtype text not null, "
    + "emailaddress text not null);";

private static final String TABLE_5 =
    "create table address (_addressid integer primary key autoincrement,"
    + "userid integer not null, addresstype text not null, "
    + "address text not null);";

private static final String TABLE_6 = 
    "create table instantmessaging (_imid integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "userid integer not null, imtype text not null, "
    + "imaccount text not null);";

public void createTables(){
    db.execSQL(TABLE_1);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_2);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_3);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_4);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_5);
}
 db.execSQL(TABLE_6);
```

Answer (score -3):

put **Go** after each Create Table statement

Updated script

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table credentials (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "username text not null, password text not null, "
                + "lastupdate text); Go;"
      + "create table user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "firstname text not null, "
                + "lastname text not null); Go;"
      + "create table phone (_phoneid integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "userid integer not null, phonetype text not null, "
                + "phonenumber text not null); Go;"
      + "create table email (_emailid integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "userid integer not null, emailtype text not null, "
                + "emailaddress text not null) Go;;"
      + "create table address (_addressid integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "userid integer not null, addresstype text not null, "
                + "address text not null); Go;"
      + "create table instantmessaging (_imid integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "userid integer not null, imtype text not null, "
                + "imaccount text not null); Go;";
```

Comment: than try to break each statement than execute and see the result because there might be exception cause by the one of the statement