# SQLite3 - Create multiple tables in one statement

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm learning node js at the mo, and using SQLite3 to create a portable project/task/workflow tool (it'll eventually end up on github).

If it's the first time a user is running the node app (and the SQLite database file does not exist), I want it to run an install SQL script to create all the tables it'll need to work.

I could do them all as separate transactions, but that looks messy and it's much easier to do it all in one call.

In Oracle I know I can wrap them all in as follows:

```
BEGIN CREATE TABLE1...; CREATE TABLE2...; END;
```

SQLite though, I don't know as much about (and don't know if I can do what I am trying to do).

The code below is only create the first table (and not the others).

Thanks.

**Express Node JS app calling the SQL on startup**

```
// Declare Express
var express   = require('express');

// Instantiate Express
var app       = express();

// Create a http server with express
var server    = require('http').createServer(app);

// Instantiate socket on the http express server
var io        = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Declare filesystem
var fs        = require('fs');

// Database File  
var db_file   = './sqlite/db-rhubarb.sqlite';

// Check if the dataexists
var db_exists = fs.existsSync(db_file);

// Declare sqlite3
var sqlite3   = require('sqlite3').verbose();

// Instantiate sqlite3 database
var db        = new sqlite3.Database(db_file);

// Check if a database exists - create if on first run
db.serialize(function() {
  //if (!fs.existsSync(db_file)) {
    console.log("Can't find a SQLite database, creating one now...");
    var install_sql = fs.readFileSync('./sqlite/sql/install.sql', 'utf-8');
    db.run(install_sql);

  //}
});

// Application port (this is what eg localhost:1227)
var port      = 1127;

// Tell server listen on port
server.listen(port);
console.log("Running application on port: "+port);
```

**Install SQL**

```
/* Create the contacts table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'main'.'contacts' ( "contact_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL  UNIQUE, 
                                           "date_added" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                           "user_id_created" INTEGER );

/* Create the contacts attribute table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"."contact_attributes" ( "cont_attr_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, 
                                                     "contact_id" INTEGER, 
                                                     "date_created" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                                     "user_id_created" INTEGER, 
                                                     "attr_name" VARCHAR, 
                                                     "attr_value" VARCHAR );

/* Create the task table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"."tasks" ( "task_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                        "date_created" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                        "user_id_created" INTEGER,
                                        "task_value" VARCHAR );

/* Create the tag table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"."tags" ( "tag_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
                                       "date_created" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                       "user_id_created" INTEGER, 
                                       "tag_value" VARCHAR UNIQUE );

/* Create the tag mapping table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"."map_tag_task" ( "map_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT     NOT NULL  UNIQUE, 
                                               "date_created" DATETIME DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                               "user_id_created" INTEGER, 
                                               "tag_id" INTEGER, 
                                               "task_id" INTEGER );

/* Create the log table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"."logs" ( "log_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, 
                                        "date_created" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                        "user_id_created" INTEGER, 
                                        "task_id" INTEGER,
                                        "log_value" VARCHAR );

/* Create the task messages table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"."messages" ( "message_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                           "date_created" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                           "user_id_created" INTEGER,
                                           "task_id" INTEGER,
                                           "message_value" VARCHAR );

/* Create the users table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"."users" ( "user_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                        "forename" VARCHAR,
                                        "surname" VARCHAR,
                                        "password" VARCHAR,
                                        "salt" VARCHAR );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done... Found this answer on Stack Overflow with a similar issue:

[Only first table in create table statement being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928184/only-first-table-in-create-table-statement-being-created?rq=1)