# SQLite + MyBatis inserting null value for autoincrement primary key

Tags: java, sqlite, mybatis

I am attempting to use a single MyBatis implementation in my Java/Gradle project to read/write from either a live MySQL instance or a static SQLite instance (currently using a file for debugging purposes, but hopefully in memory long term). Everything is working fine with MySQL, but for some reason when I use SQLite the integer primary key (which should be mirroring rowID afaik) is being written as null. At first I thought maybe this was how the rowID alias was implemented, but once a record is inserted it cannot be fetched using its rowID in the id field.

Create statement for the SQLite table:

```
DROP TABLE `event`;
CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    `time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `duration` INT NOT NULL,
    `summary_id` INT NOT NULL
);
```

MyBatis mapper for get and insert:

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM event WHERE id=#{id}")
Event get(final int id);

@Insert({"INSERT INTO",
    "event(time, duration, summary_id)",
    "VALUES(#{e.time}, #{e.duration}, #{summaryId})"})
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty = "result.id")
void insert(@Param("e") final Event item, @Param("summaryId") final int summaryId, @Param("result") final IdentifierResult result);
```

`IdentifierResult` is a simple wrapper around an `int` that captures the id of the record created.

I have tried creating the id with every valid combination of `INTEGER`, `NOT NULL`, and `PRIMARY KEY` with and without `AUTOINCREMENT`, all with the same result. I have also tried writing a single dummy row immediately after creating the table with its id explicitly set to 1, but subsequent entries were still written with a null id.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With that method signature, you may have to pass an instance of `IdentifierResult` as the last argument when calling the method. MyBatis, then, assigns the generated key to the `id` field of the instance (assuming that `IdentifierResult` is a POJO-ish mutable object).

Comment: This is Java, so if I wasn't passing an appropriate object there then it wouldn't compile. However, the id field cannot be properly populated because the id field in the table itself is null.

Comment: What I meant was that you cannot pass `null` as the last argument. I'm not familiar with SQLite very much, but it seems to work fine. Try this portable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-75850617).

Comment: My initial reaction was 'well of COURSE you can't pass null' but if you're accounting for it I'm sure you've probably seen someone do it  Finally figured this one out, it was a SQL problem after all. Will write it up when I get a sec.

Comment: People surprise me every once in a while  Anyway, I'm glad to know that you found the cause. 

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this had nothing to do with MyBatis or my code at all and was just a compounding of a couple smaller mistakes:

1. My project was loading a sqlite db file with improperly initialized tables, causing my various attempts at changing the create statements to be basically ignored.
2. A single file containing all my create statements was [only executing the first statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928184/only-first-table-in-create-table-statement-being-created).

I deleted the bad resource and split my creates out into individual files and, except for the places where my frantic testing lead me to mess up my DAO mappers, things are running smoothly.